# p-calendar is automatically closing when scrolling in Firefox browser

Tags: angular, primeng

The PrimeNG calendar automatically close when we scroll the page. The issue only exists on Mozilla Firefox, and working fine in all other browsers.

```
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar
```

Please can somebody help me. Thanks

Comment: Can someone suggest an alternative for overflow: overlay style in Mozilla Firefox ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this property in your calender

> appendTo="body"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).